# Where did the Brahmastra, which Bhagwan Rama launched to dry up the sea, eventually fall?

Tags: ramayana, weapon, brahmastra, itihasa

At the time when Lord Rama was on his way to Lanka, he asked the sea god (sagara) for help and to make way for his journey , but the sea god didn't offer any help. Then Shree Rama activated brahmastra.

After this  when sea begged for forgiveness Shree  Raam ji shot brahamastra at someplace making that place  a desert.

I want to know the place or the name of the region, where the brahmastra fell.

Answer (score 12):

The place name is Drumatulya. It is mentioned in [Valmiki Ramayana, Yuddha Kanda, Sarga 22](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/yuddha/sarga22/yuddha_22_frame.htm).

> रामस्य वचनम् श्रुत्वा तम् च दृष्ट्वा महाशरम् || २-२२-३० 
>    महोदधिर्महातेजा राघवम् वाक्यमब्रवीत् |
>
> Hearing Rama's words and seeing that powerful arrow, the large splendid Ocean spoke the following words to Rama:
>
> उत्तरेणावकाशोऽस्ति कश्चित्पुण्यतरो मम || २-२२-३१
>   **द्रुमकुल्य इति ख्यातो** लोके ख्यातो यथा भवान् |
>
> **Towards my northern side, there is a holy place. It is well known as Drumatulya**, in the same way as you are well known to this world.
>
> उग्रदर्शनकर्माणो बहवस्तत्र दस्यवः || २-२२-३२
>   आभीरप्रमुखाः पापाः पिबन्ति सलिलम् मम |
>
> Numerous robbers of fearful aspect and deeds, having the sinful Abhiras as their chief, drink my waters there.
>
> तैर्न तत्स्पर्शनम् पापम् सहेयम् पापकर्मभिः || २-२२-३३
>   अमोघः क्रियताम् राम तत्र तेषु शरोत्तमः |
>
> I am not able to bear that touch of those wicked people, the evil doers, O, Rama! Let this excellent arrow with out vain be released over them there.
>
> तस्य तद्वचनम् श्रुत्वा सागरस्य महात्मनः || २-२२-३४
>   मुमोच तम् शरम् दीप्तम् परम् सागरदर्शनात् |
>
> Hearing those words of the high-soled Ocean, Rama released that excellent and splendid arrow towards that place as directed by the ocean.
>
> तेन **तन्मरुकान्तारम्** प्^इथिव्याम् किल विश्रुतम् || २-२२-३५
>   विपातितः शरो यत्र वज्राशनिसमप्रभः |
>
> The place where the arrow, whose splendor was akin to that of a thunder and a thunder bolt, was descended by Rama- **that place is indeed famous as desert of Maru* on this earth.**
>
> - Maru�Malwar in Rajastan (India)

Comment: what is the evidence for Maru to be present day Malwar?